# Trying to dynamically add a TextView to a ScrollView crashes when using an XML layout

Tags: android

This is a very simple example where I have a single ScrollView defined in R.layout.main.  Then I try to dynamically add a TextView to it.

Unfortunately this crashes.

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("This is tv1");

scroll.addView(tv1);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Now I *can* do something like this:

```
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("This is tv1");

scroll.addView(tv1);

setContentView(scroll);
```

But I'd really like to be able to define some base UI elements in XML, then dynamically add others.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: can you please post the log cat of crash. and also ensure that a scroll view can have only one child at a time.

Comment: No need for a stack trace as it is obvious.

Comment: flood of answers is here with all saying the same thing. whose answer should @Mark Biek will select. I am about to post this question :)

Comment: @Javanator: In theory the one that helped him most. I seriously don't understand why people don't open their eyes and pay attention to the _An answer has been posted_ message.

Comment: @Javanator: I'm not concerned about copying here but about the fact that there are an unnecessary amount of unneeded duplicates because people just disregard the message which says that the question has been answered in the meantime.

Comment: Ok i agree with you @Octavian Damiean :)

Comment: @Octavian Damiean I was only 54 secs behind you, and didn't get the `New Answer...` message.  As it turns out, I think both our answers have value, as you explain why he needs to call `setContentView`, and I explain the nature of the error he is experiencing.

Comment: i love stackoverflow for this mess only. :) Though i totally agree that there should be a discipline in answering as one should be given merit of the efforts he made. This free source community should benefit all. 
And Guys who may so ever answer first or last In the end Mark Biek got his problem resolved which is sole objective of this commnuity to provide solution who may so ever ask. :) Enjoy Everybody

Comment: and dave.c i noticed every time difference and it was not of 54 sec..:) :) it was more then 2 Minutes :)

Comment: @Javanator The timestamp on the post by Oct is 13:49:02.  My post is 13:49:56.  That is a difference of 54 seconds.

Comment: how to check that time stamp. the time i saw Octavian Damiean post was 2 min ahead posted by the 2nd in rank ..i noticed the 17 min ago and other things not any specific time stamp...

Comment: I've posted a complete solution below.  Thanks to everyone for helping to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because you are trying to access a view which hasn't been parsed by Android yet.

When you define a layout using XML, then you have to call `setContentView` first, passing it the layout file reference so that Android can parse the file. Only then you can access the elements using `findViewById`.

That basically means that you should call `setContentView` *before* trying to access any element of your layout.

Answer (score 2):

You must call setContentView before you doing anything else with any views.

This should work.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("This is tv1");

scroll.addView(tv1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this,

You can create a new `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`, and set the id as say, `layoutinside`

now

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutinside);
 TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
 tv1.setText("This is tv1");

 ll.addView(tv1);
```

This is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` should only be called after you have called `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.  Currently `scroll` will be `null` so I would expect it to throw a `NullPointerException` at `scroll.addView(tv1);`

Answer (score 1):

i Got your problem . You need to set the contentView as like this before

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("This is tv1");

scroll.addView(tv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

While needing to have `setContentView()` at the beginning was part of the problem, it turns out that it wasn't the source of the exception.

The actual exception being thrown was `IllegalStateException "Scrollview can host only one direct child"` (which [Javanator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467592/javanator) touched on in the comments)

When I looked at the XML for the ScrollView, it looked like this.  Eclipse automatically adds a LinearLayout when a ScrollView is added to the layout:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So, there are two ways to fix the exception:

**1)**  Remove the LinearLayout from inside the ScrollView.  Then, after moving my call to `setContentView` to the top, the code in my question works.

**2)**  Instead of adding the TextView to the ScrollView, I can add the TextView to the LinearLayout instead like this:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
 TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
 tv1.setText("This is tv1");

 ll.addView(tv1);
```